# Java ArrayList search and remove

Tags: java, arraylist

I am attempting to search through an array list to find a value (which may reoccur) and remove all instances of that value. I also would like to remove from a separate array list, values that are at the same location. Both ArrayLists are `ArrayList<String>`.

For example I am looking for the number 5 in ArrayList2:

```
ArrayList 1       ArrayList2
cat               1
pig               2
dog               5
chicken           3
wolf              5
```

Once I find the number 5, in both locations, I would like to remove dog and wolf from ArrayList1. My code has no errors but it doesn't seem to be actually removing what I am asking it.

```
//searching for
String s="5";
//for the size of the arraylist
for(int p=0; p<ArrayList2.size(); p++){
 //if the arraylist has th value of s
 if(ArrayList2.get(p).contains(s)){
   //get the one to remove
   String removethis=ArrayList2.get(p);
   String removetoo=ArrayList1.get(p);
   //remove them
   ArrayList2.remove(removethis);
   ArrayList1.remove(removetoo);
  }
}
```

When I print the arrayLists they look largely unchanged. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you not want to use a `Map<String, Integer>`?  It would simplify this process a great deal.

Comment: I don't know of Map<String, Integer>... I will see what I can find on it. Thanks

Comment: agree with @Makoto on: why maintain two parallel Lists? Some other data structure then List may be more suitable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you are both looping and removing items from an array, the algorithm you wrote is incorrect because it skips the next item following each removal (due to the way in which you increment p). Consider this alternative:

```
int s = 5;
int idx = 0;

while (idx < ArrayList2.size())
{
   if(ArrayList2.get(idx) == s)
   {
     // Remove item
     ArrayList1.remove(idx);
     ArrayList2.remove(idx);
  }
  else
  {
    ++idx;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked very well! I know see how I was changing the array size while iterating. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate over a collection and remove elements of the same collection, then you'll have to use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), e.g.:

```
List<String> names = ....
List<Integer> numbers = ....
int index = 0;
Iterator<String> i = names.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   String s = i.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()
   if (s.equals("dog"){
       i.remove();
       numbers.remove(index);
   }
   index++;
}
```

**EDIT**

In your case, you'll have to manually increment a variable to be able to remove items from the other List.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two iterators:

```
Iterator<String> i1 = arrayList1.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> i2 = arrayList2.iterator();
while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
  i1.next();
  if (i2.next() == s) {
    i1.remove();
    i2.remove();
  }
}
```

Though as has been pointed out yet, it would probably be easier to use a map.

Answer (score 0):

I think the contains method compares the two objects. However, the object "s" is different from the object in the ArrayList. You should use typed arrays (i.e. ArrayList) and make sure to compare values of each objects, not the objects themselves ...

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Could you explain further?

Comment: The problem is, that the object "s" of value 5 is different instance than the objects with values 5 in the List. The contains method return true, if both objects are the same, it is the same instance. Therefore it always returns false for you in your code and the objects are not removed.
The solution was already written by many others. Use typed lists and use equals method instead of plain ArrayList and contains method.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your list as follows -

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
//...
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//...
```

And instead of `contains` method use `equals` method.

Also to remove while iterating the lists use `Iterator` which you can get as follows -

```
Iterator<String> it1 = list1.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> it2 = list2.iterator();

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the [indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method of ArrayList, but you have to be careful when removing from a list while iterating on it's elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight forward solution:

```
List<Integer> origNums = new ArrayList<Integer>(nums);
Iterator<String> animalIter = animals.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> numIter = nums.iterator();

while (animalIter.hasNext()) {
    animalIter.next();

    // Represents a duplicate?
    if (Collections.frequency(origNums, numIter.next()) > 1) {

        // Remove current element from both lists.
        animalIter.remove();
        numIter.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(animals); // [cat, pig, chicken]
System.out.println(nums);    // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Makoto, using Map maybe more beneficial. If you will be searching only using the values of ArrayList2, then you have multiple values for one key.
For example, 5 refers to dog and wolf. For this you can add a list of values to the key - 5.

```
HashMap aMap = HashMap();

ArrayList key5 = new ArrayList();

key5.add("dog");
key5.add("wolf");

aMap.put(5, key5);
```

So when you need to remove all values for 5, you do

```
aMap.remove(5);
```

And it will remove the list containing dog and wolf.