# Monster object deletion

Tags: java, object

Short introduction:
I'm building a game, where monsters spawn at the top, and moves through a path, to the reach a point where they need to be removed/destroyed/deleted. But I can't seem to get the Monster Object deleted.

```
for (Monster i : Monstre) 
    {
        this.add(i); //adds monster to JPanel

if(i.monstery > 50 && i.monsterx > 50){  //check if monster have reached end point

        this.remove(i); //Should remove Object from the JPanel ?
        i = null; //Sets object too null
        Monstre.remove(i); //Removes object from arrayList "Monstre".

}else{
//Update the monsters bounds
```

The above removes the object from the JPanel, and it seems to be all good. But when i call `System.out.println(Monstre.size());` I get an increasing amount of monsters spawned, and if increasing the monster spawn rate, the program starts to eventually slow down, because amount of monsters in the Monstre arraylist is over 9000, and never decreasing.
What I'm looking for, is a way to remove these objects while the game is running.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Also - not sure what type Monstre is. But you are deleting elements from the collection that you are iterating (Monstre.remove(i)). That is not good practice (or can at least lead to undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `i = null;` line. This is not *C* and you don't have to assign your variables to `null`. JVM will do that for you (google "java garbage collection"). Because of that line, you practically call `Monstre.remove(null)` which does not work.

Also, you cannot iterate over the collection in that manner and modify it (remove values). Save the monsters you want to delete in an array outside of the scope of the loop, and remove them after the loop finishes. Otherwise, use an iterator:

```
Iterator<Monster> it= Monstre.iterator(); 
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Monster i= it.next();
    //code code code
    if (shouldDelete) {
        this.remove(i);
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: If removing i = null;
The program returns Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)

Comment: @JesperTuborgMadsen Then that is your real problem

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the suggestion in the first answer, you should change your loop. Removing items from the `Monstre` list while using the for-each loop will cause problems.

Instead try :

```
 Iterator<Monster> iter = Monstre.iterator ();
 while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        i = iter.next();
        this.add(i); //adds monster to JPanel

        if(i.monstery > 50 && i.monsterx > 50){  //check if monster have reached end point

            this.remove(i);
            iter.remove();

        }else{
```

EDIT :

Here's an explanation where you can't use the [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) :

> So when should you use the for-each loop? Any time you can. It really
>   beautifies your code. Unfortunately, you cannot use it everywhere.
>   Consider, for example, the expurgate method. The program needs access
>   to the iterator in order to **remove** the current element. The for-each
>   loop hides the iterator, so **you cannot call remove**. Therefore, the
>   for-each loop is not usable for filtering. Similarly it is not usable
>   for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you
>   traverse it. Finally, it is not usable for loops that must iterate
>   over multiple collections in parallel. These shortcomings were known
>   by the designers, who made a conscious decision to go with a clean,
>   simple construct that would cover the great majority of cases.

Comment: Now the writer of the original answer added the Iterator code, so his answer works too.

Comment: I'll have to do some read up on iterators - Thanks for the help! : )

Answer (score 2):

```
    i = null; //Sets object too null
    Monstre.remove(i); //Removes object from arrayList "Monstre".
```

Here you set the variable i to null then you request that i (i.e. null) is removed from your arraylist, the arraylist does not contain null so nothing happens. Setting things equal to null is very rarely nessissary.

As you have correctly said removing the i=null upsets the program, this is because you are iterating through the list and then changing the list while iterating, you have two options;

1) go through the Arraylist in a manor similar to an array

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<Double> doubles=new  ArrayList<Double>();

        for(double i=0;i<10;i++){
            doubles.add(i);
        }

        //remove 7.0s from doubles

        for(int i=doubles.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
            //must go through backwards - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111210/java-arraylist-search-and-remove for why

            if (doubles.get(i).equals(7.0)){
                doubles.remove(i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

2) use an iterator and its remove method

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<Double> doubles=new  ArrayList<Double>();

        for(double i=0;i<10;i++){
            doubles.add(i);
        }

        //remove 7.0s from doubles

        Iterator<Double> iterator=doubles.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Double testDouble=iterator.next();
            if (testDouble.equals(7.0)){
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove this element in a `for-loop`.

You need to use `listIterator()` method to retrieve an iterator that can be modified and loop with iterator-style. Otherwise you would always get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException